# Using .eps file in journal of material science template on Mac

Tags: epstopdf

I am using TeXworks on a Mac to run a LaTeX template of Journal of Materials Science. The template contains `.eps` files as all the pictures should be in `.eps`. I am getting the following error message:

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `example-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found:
using draft setting.
```

I tried to find the solution here but couldn't find any. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You are not really giving us any information here. What kind of system are you on. Are you using TeXLive or Miktex. Can we see the code you are using.

Comment: Hi daleif, Many thanks for your quick reply. I am using Texworks and the code is as follows:

Comment: I am trying to include the code and its giving me warning " too long". Sorry. any suggestion how to post a long code?

Comment: The only way I was able to reproduce your problem was by removing the `filecontents` block named `example.eps` at the beginning of the proposed template and by also deleting the `example.eps` and `example-eps-converted-to.pdf` files in the folder. I guess you have removed them. A way of solving your problem is to also remove the `\begin{figure} \end{figure}` blocks in which the `\includegraphics{example.eps}` command appear (be careful, there are two).

Comment: Do not add code to explain your problem in the comments, edit your original question to add it.

Comment: Thanks KersouMan. I tried removing two sets of \begin{figure} \end{figure} and it worked, but my question was how can I run without removing them?

Comment: Don't remove the `\begin{filecontents*}{example.eps} \end{filecontents*}{example.eps}` block at the beginning of the document. This way, you will still get the `example.eps` figure generated and you will be able to include it.

Comment: Many thanks Kersouman. I tried blocking \begin{filecontents*}{example.eps} \end{filecontents*}{example.eps} but still getting the same error message :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101733/discussion-between-tasnuva-and-kersouman).